# SOLID - Dependency Inversion principle deve se aplicar também a funções utilitárias simples?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, classes, solid

Ao seguir os princípios do SOLID, o D (Dependency inversion principle) diz para dependermos de interfaces e não de implementações concretas. Isso se aplica também para funções utilitárias, que ajuda a deixar o código mais "limpo"?

Veja o exemplo 1, onde tem um código "sujo" no IF, que verifica se um objeto é vazio ou não. Então criei uma função utilitária para tornar o código mais limpo. Essa função deveria ser uma interface (exemplo 3) ou posso aplicá-la diretamente na minha classe (exemplo 2)? Note que aplico a inversão de dependências para a database, visto que é uma implementação complexa, a dúvida é realmente para funções utilitárias simples.

O exemplo a seguir é totalmente fictício e foi criado só para ilustrar minha dúvida, ignore se não faz muito sentido o exemplo.

EXEMPLO 01:

```
export class UserRepository {
  constructor (private readonly database: DatabaseProtocol) {}

  async findUserByEmail (data: Record<string, any>): Promise<IUser | null> {
    const userCollection = this.database.collection('users')

    if (Object.keys(data).length === 0) return null

    const user = await userCollection.findOne({ email: data.email })

    return user
  }
}
```

EXEMPLO 02

```
export class UserRepository {
  constructor (private readonly database: DatabaseProtocol) {}

  async findUserByEmail (data: Record<string, any>): Promise<IUser | null> {
    const userCollection = this.database.collection('users')

    if (isEmpty(data)) return null

    const user = await userCollection.findOne({ email: data.email })

    return user
  }
}
```

EXEMPLO 03

```
export class UserRepository {
  constructor (
    private readonly database: DatabaseProtocol,
    private readonly isEmpty: IsEmptyProtocol
  ) {}

  async findUserByEmail (data: Record<string, any>): Promise<IUser | null> {
    const userCollection = this.database.collection('users')

    if (this.isEmpty(data)) return null

    const user = await userCollection.findOne({ email: data.email })

    return user
  }
}
```

Comment: Por questão de código, pensando que sua função `isEmpty` seja considerado um utils na qual pode ser replicado pelo código inteiro. Talvez fica inviável você fazer uma injeção de dependência de um cara que faz algo simples. Mas também uma dúvida que fiquei, por quais motivos você verifica se o `data` é vazio? Você encontrar o usuário por e-mail, não precisa simplesmente do e-mail passado, e não em si um objeto que contenha o e-mail?
Entendemos que é apenas um exemplo, porém trazer exemplos que sejam mais coerentes, ajuda ao contribuinte responder melhor.

Comment: @VagnerWentz esse código não é real, inventei só pra tentar criar um exemplo que ficasse fácil de visualizar. Desconsidere se não faz sentido, pois não quis perder muito tempo pensando em algo mais realístico.

Comment: Vai depender do contexto, mas no caso do exemplo, pode ser simplesmente uma função sem ser uma injeção de dependência. É muito comum fazer uma injeção de dependência com interfaces quando são contratos que regem outras bibliotecas, podemos pensar no caso de um Email Validator, usamos alguma biblioteca onde nós criamos nossa própria implementação, mas no fundo, quem valida é a biblioteca, assim temos um Adapter que segue a interface própria nossa e não em si de uma biblioteca. Assim podemos injetar, seria também mesma coisa para um Crypto Adapter para criptografia de senha.

Answer (score 0):

Olá, nesse caso do exemplo você pode usa-la diretamente, visto que também não esta criando/instanciando sua implementação dentro da classe, assim não gera acoplamento, porém gosto da idéia de aplicar o princípio, vai de sua preferência e de seu projeto!

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).